# Public key authentication on SunSSH fails

Tags: ssh, solaris, opensolaris, openindiana

I'm using OpenIndiana 151a on x86 and I want to connect to other remote servers using ssh with public key authentication, but it fails.

The remote server's sshd (OpenSSH) is enabled with ssh-2 protocol. I already have ssh client installed in my OpenIndiana. I can connect to remote host using password authentication.

However, when I try to connect using public key authentication, I get the following error message.

```
    openindiana% ssh user@host
    ssh_rsa_sign: RSA_sign failed:
    error:8006B076:lib(128):PK11_GET_PRIV_RSA_KEY:C_CreateObject failed
    user@host's password:
```

Note that the remote server's sshd is already working with public key authentication, I didn't forget to add my public key string inside id_rsa.pub to the remote server's .ssh/authorized_keys. Public key authentication succeeds in other OpenSSH clients.

This, I think, is SunSSH's problem. I found out that these problems occur only in OpenSolaris, OpenIndiana and Oracle Solaris 11 express.

Are there any solutions to make my OpenIndiana work with public key authentication? I don't want to change to Linux or *BSD because there are a bunch of Solaris machines still working in my office.

Hope this may help :

```
    openindiana% uname -a
    SunOS s2 5.11 oi_151a i86pc i386 i86pc
    openindiana% ssh -V
    Sun_SSH_1.5, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x009080ff
    openindiana%
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on some testing I just did myself, the problem appears to be keys with sizes other than 2048 bits. When I generated a new key that was 2048 bits (the default), everything worked just fine.

Comment: I can confirm this, except it seems keys up to 4096 bits are fine (4097 bits fails).

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `-vvv` to `ssh` and read more detailed debug information.